# Vim UTF8 characters in terminal

Tags: vim, terminal

So I am editing a UTF8 file in terminal vim and all of a sudden these weird characters come up when I press then navigation keys. So the image attached shows one such character being printed onto the screen after moving up from the end of the file. These guys are merely printed but never saved into the buffer. When that line moves out of view and then back, the character is not printed again. This is a completely random event and never seems to happen at the same location. One exception is I am at the end of the file and happen to press the down key repeatedly.

[image]

EDIT: New image for `:Set term=cons25`

[image: image2]

Comment: what is your TERM variable set to? And are you using  `hjkl` for navigation or the arrow key?

Comment: I am using xterm and the arrow keys give out these characters while the `hjkl` keys print out the letters.

Comment: `echo $TERM`. are you local or remote?  This happens when the control codes that the arrow keys are sending are not correct for the TERM setting. IE you are setting a TERM of `xterm` and the remote doesn't understand it.  try `:set term=cons25` in vim and see if that fixes it

Comment: I did both `echo $TERM` and `:set term`, both say I am using xterm. I am on my local machine.

Comment: Nope it worsens the problem. I have attached a new image to the question.

Answer (score 1):

These escape characters appear when Vim is confused about what key presses it receives from the terminal emulator. The arrow keys are received as `Escape` followed by a character from `A` to `D`:

- `^]0A` is `<up>`,
- `^]0B` is `<down>`,
- `^]0C` is `<right>`
- `^]0D` is `<left>`.

Editing an UTF-8 file has nothing to do with your issue.

Here is what I have in my `/.vimrc` to work around that problem:

```
nnoremap <Esc>A <up>
nnoremap <Esc>B <down>
nnoremap <Esc>C <right>
nnoremap <Esc>D <left>
inoremap <Esc>A <up>
inoremap <Esc>B <down>
inoremap <Esc>C <right>
inoremap <Esc>D <left>
```

I'm not aware of a better solution.

Comment: Well I agree with what you have to say but what I don't understand is why this started all of a sudden. I did not encounter this before, ever.

Comment: as for all of a sudden did you make any changes / update software?  do you have a .vimrc file?

Comment: Yes I do have a .vimrc file, [here](https://github.com/stangirala/vimrc/blob/master/.vimrc). My most recent change was something to the statusline. As for this answer, I am confused about how vim can navigate and yet misunderstand the keys. If I press `j` and I do move, then at some point it is able to read the input but not act on it. I assume it prints to screen and clears when it does some action?

Comment: Does reverting your latest change help in any way? Also, your git branch thing is very inefficient: the statusline is updated many times per second so your system call is also done many times per second as well.

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. I'm guessing its too many updates on the status line.